# Position element at the bottom of a fixed position div

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I'm looking to position a `div` within a `position: fixed` div at the bottom of the parent `div`.  The only conditions are that the parent div has to have `position: fixed`, and the element should become hidden if the page is vertically resizes.

The only solution I have discovered follows this JSFiddle I made:  http://jsfiddle.net/WhnFc/

The problem with this solution, however, is that if the page is vertically resized, the `div` positioned at the bottom will stay at the bottom of the page and not become hidden.

Are there any other solutions or tricks to solve this w/out using JS?

Comment: The parent element should become hidden? Or the child div should become hidden? And why? We need to know what exact behavior you're looking for; when the page is vertically resized at all? 1px shorter? 50px shorter? Resized enough to cover the div?

Comment: So all you need to know is how to make the element hidden when vertically resizingthe window?

Comment: The child div.  Think of the parent div as having other child elements inside of it, and so if the window is resizes, and the bottom child `div` doesn't become hidden, it would float on top of the other child elements, which is unwanted functionality..

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment but I think the only way to hide the div when you resize it is to use media queries

For example, if the browser window get's smaller then 500px it wouldn't be shown

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 500px) {.bottom { display:none; }}
```